# Search results showing duplicate entries

Tags: 7, views

For some reason the search results show duplicate entire with the view I have, I also have  distinct on under the query options so it doesn't show duplicate nodes, I cant figure out why its doing this for the life of me.

This is the view I have of it.
[image]

Any input is appreciated.

Edit: It seems to only do this when I search for  only 2 words, for example "should I" "can you" "this that" "now here" ect...

Comment: go to Views settings and enable "Show the SQL query" so that you can figure out if the problem is with the query or views

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have added a field (Field: Image). If there are nodes with multiple field items (multiple images), then they will show up multiple times. To avoid that, enable aggregation in the advanced settings. It might also be possible to configure the field to only list the first value, not exactly sure.

Comment: I will try what you said, please take a look at my edit, thanks